# Exception of type 'Web.TPEngine.Providers.BadArgumentRetryNeededException' was thrown

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

When users try to sign-in they receive "Your password is incorrect" but I know the username/password is valid.

I configured the [user journey recorder](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%205.md#placing-the-desired-relying-party-policy-in-development-mode) and I'm receiving the following:

> Exception of type 'Web.TPEngine.Providers.BadArgumentRetryNeededException' was thrown.

What does this error mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, when the [ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#create-the-proxyidentityexperienceframework-application) Azure AD App was created, it was created incorrectly.  It was created as a Web app / API, not a **native app** like it was supposed to be.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

@spottedmahn is 100% correct. For me, I missed the **Grant Permissions** part.

Also, you must do **both of these**

- configure the IdentityExperienceFramework permission
- **click Grant Permissions**

[image]

PS. Did I mention that if you don't click **Grant Permissions** nothing will work; seriously!

Answer (score 0):

All of the above is absolutely correct:

1. ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework application type MUST be **Native**
2. MUST configure permission and do not forget to click "**Grant Permissions**"

Also what gets me almost every time is forgetting to paste the Application ID's for *ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework* and *IdentityExperienceFramework* into the XML policy, under the "login-NonInteractive" technical profile.

Like this:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account SignIn</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="client_id">xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</Item><!-- ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework -->
        <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</Item><!-- IdentityExperienceFramework -->
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" /> <!-- ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" /> <!-- IdentityExperienceFramework -->
      </InputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```